# POSTing a nested object ruins the encoding in NodeJS Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, utf-8

I am having trouble sending JSON data that contains special characters like `` ` `` to my Node Express server.

I posted *[How can I render UTF-8 characters in JSX without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64073935/how-can-i-render-utf-8-characters-in-jsx-without-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-i)* earlier, but I think I am approaching the problem incorrectly.

> **The Problem:**

When I submit my JSON form data using an HTTP Client, my `req.body` *HTMLifies* special characters:

```js
// Sending a nested JSON.stringified Object
const response1 = await fetch(
  `${baseUrl}/chhands/${granthState.lastChhand.id}/pauris`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      pauri: formattedTuk,
      last_pauri_id: granthState.lastPauri?.id,
    }),
  }
);
```

Here is a result of the `console.log`ging `{pauri: formattedTuk, last_pauri_id: granthState.lastPauri?.id}`:

[image]

> **What it looks like on the backend when I submit the nested JSON object:**
> [image]

> **Here is where the where I am even MORE confused:**

Here, instead of sending a nested object, I only send the `formattedTuk` [Array] object, which looks like:

```js
[
  {
    line_number: 1,
    content_unicode: 'ਆਪ ਅਛਤ ਸਮਰੱਥ ਪ੍ਰਭੁ ਦਈ ਬਡਾਈ ਨਾਮ ।',
    content_gs: 'Awp ACq smr`Q pRBu deI bfweI nwm [',
    content_transliteration_english:
      "aap achhat samara'th prabh dhiee baddaiee naam |",
    first_letters: 'ਆਅਸਪਦਬਨ',
    thamkis: [],
    vishraams: [],
  },
];
```

```
// Sending the raw array object stringified {}
const response2 = await fetch(
  `${baseUrl}/chhands/${granthState.lastChhand.id}/pauris`,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(formattedTuk),
  }
);
```

> **What it looks like on the backend when I submit the ONLY the Array Object:**
> [image]

Other things I've tried:

- Used Axios (instead node-fetch) and it gave the same effect
- Used POSTMAN and it had the same effect
- Double checked my `Content-Type` and `charset` but it all looks good.

Here is my Express middleware settings. I was using `body-parser` before, but it seems that `express.json()` is giving me the same effect. I've also seen people recommend using `qs.stringify()` but what I am doing seems fairly simple.

```js
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
```

> **Updates:**

1. Here is the exact "Copy as Fetch" value:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:1469/api/v1/chhands/53/pauris", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site"
  },
  "referrer": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "{\"pauri\":[{\"line_number\":1,\"content_unicode\":\"ਆਪ ਅਛਤ ਸਮਰੱਥ ਪ੍ਰਭੁ ਦਈ ਬਡਾਈ ਨਾਮ ।\",\"content_gs\":\"Awp ACq smr`Q pRBu deI bfweI nwm [\",\"content_transliteration_english\":\"aap achhat samara'th prabh dhiee baddaiee naam |\",\"first_letters\":\"ਆਅਸਪਦਬਨ\",\"thamkis\":[],\"vishraams\":[]}],\"last_pauri_id\":60}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

Comment: This feels more likely an issue with how formattedTuk was created, instead of what client you use.

Comment: How so? When I log it, it is **exactly** what's expected. Furthermore, if I send the same response in the Postman, like: `{"pauri": [{...}], "last_pauri_id": 60}` it is still giving the weird encoding.

Comment: Can you share your exact "fetch" request ? You can do so by right clicking on the request in "Network" section and selecting "Copy as fetch" from the opening context menu. (It's only working in Chrome / Chromium)

Comment: @dsomel21 i might be wrong then! apologies

Comment: @ErolKESKİN I've edited in that "fetch" request. A very useful feature, but in there, we can see that we are sending the correct characters.

Comment: I can't think of any solutions. Do you process that JSON with any HTML library in Backend ? If you are not it's really a weird issue

Comment: I completely overlooked my express-validator middleware. It must be from `.escape()` method. Once I get to the bottom of it, I will answer my own question. This thread was very useful, nonetheless.